# Processing a text file where the fields are not consistent

Tags: c#

A vendor is providing a delimited text file but the file can and likely will be custom for each customer. So if the specification provides 100 fields I may only receive 10 fields.

My concern is the overhead of each loop. In all I am using a while and 2 for loops just for the header and there will at least as many for the detail.

My answer is as follows:

```
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(flName))
        {
            //Process first line to get field names
            flHeader = sr.ReadLine().Split(charDelimiters);

            //Check first field to determine header or detail file
            if (flHeader[0].ToUpper() == "ORDERID")
            {
                header = true;
            } else if (flHeader[0].ToUpper() == "ORDERITEMID"){
                detail = true;
            }
        }

        //Use TextFieldParser to read and parse files
        using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(flName))
        {
            parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
            parser.SetDelimiters(delimiters);

            while (!parser.EndOfData)
            {
                string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
                //Send read line to header or detail processor
                if (header == true)
                {
                    if (flHeader[0] != fields[0])
                    {
                        ProcessHeader(fields);
                    }
                }

                if (detail == true)
                {
                    if (flHeader[0] != fields[0])
                    {
                        ProcessDetail(fields);
                    }
                }
            }
```

//Header Processor snippet

```
        //Declare header class
        Data.BLL.OrderExportHeader_BLL OrderHeaderBLL = new Data.BLL.OrderExportHeader_BLL();
        foreach (string field in fields)
        {
            int fldCnt = fields.Count();
            //Loop through each field then use the switch to determine which field is to be filled in
            for (int flds = 0; flds < fldCnt; flds++ )
            {
                string strField = field.Trim();
                switch (flHeader[flds].ToUpper())
                {
                    case "ORDERID":
                        OrderHeaderBLL.OrderID = strField;
                        break;
                 }
             }
          }
```

//header file

```
OrderID ManufacturerID  CustomerID  SalesRepID  PONumber    OrderDate   CustomerName    CustomerNumber  RepNumber   Discount    Terms   ShipVia Notes   ShipToCompanyName   ShipToContactName   ShipToContactPhone  ShipToFax   ShipToContactEmail  ShipToAddress1  ShipToAddress2  ShipToCity  ShipToState ShipToZip   ShipToCountry   ShipDate    BillingAddress1 BillingAddress2 BillingCity BillingState    BillingZip  BillingCountry  FreightTerm PriceLevel  OrderType   OrderStatus IsPlaced    ContactName ContactPhone    ContactEmail    ContactFax  Exported    ExportDate  Source  ContainerName   ContainerCubes  Origin  MarketName  FOB SubTotal    OrderTotal  TaxRate TaxTotal    ShippingTotal   IsDeleted   IsContainer OrderGUID   CancelDate  DoNotShipBefore WrittenByName   WrittenForName  WrittenForRepNumber CatalogCode CatalogName ShipToCode
491975  18  0   2621    1234    7/17/2014   RepZio  2499174     0           Test            561-351-7416        max@repzio.com  465 Ocean Ridge Way     Juno Beach  FL  33408       7/18/2014   465 Ocean Ridge Way     Juno Beach  FL  33408   USA     0       ShopZio True    Max Fraser  561-351-7416    max@repzio.com      False       ShopZio     0.00        ShopZio     1500.0000   1500.0000   0.000   0.0000  0.0000  False   False   63960a7b-86b7-47a2-ad11-9763a6b52fd0    7/31/2014   7/18/2014
```

Comment: You can provide some example files?

Comment: Do you mean an example text file?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: It screwed up the data when I posted it but the headers have posted ok.

Comment: Are spaces in provided text file example random? It should by exact as Vendor provided, becouse it's a problem to parse "ShopZio True" one space separator and "465 Ocean Ridge Way" one space separator.

Comment: This file was provided to me as a tab delimited file. I account for both tab and comma delimited though.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data is the key, and your sample is currently obscure, but I think it matches the description that follows.

Per your example of 10 fields out of a possible 100.

In parsing each line, you only need to split in into 10 fields. It looks like you are delimited by whitespace, but you have a problem in that fields can contain embedded whitespace. Perhaps your data is actually tab delimited in which case you are ok.

For simplicity, I am going to assume your 100 fields are name 'fld0', 'fld1', ..., 'fld99'

Now, assuming the received file contains this header

fld10, fld50, fld0, fld20, fld80, fld70, fld0, fld90, fld50, fld60

and a line of data looks like

Alpha Bravo Charlie Delta Echo Foxtrot Golf Hotel India Juliet

e.g.

split[0] = "Alpha", split[1] = "Bravo", etc.

You parse the header and find that the indexes in your master list of 100 fields are 10,50,0 etc.
So you build a lookupFld array with these index value, i.e., lookupFld[0] = 10, lookupFld[1] = 50, etc

Now, as you process each line, split into 10 fields and you have an immediate indexed lookup of the correct corresponding field in your master field list.

Now MasterList[0] = "fld0", MasterList[1] = "fld1", ..., MasterList[99] = "fld99"

```
for (ii=0; ii<lookupFld.count; ++ii)
{
    // MasterField[lookupFld[ii]] is represented by with split[ii]

    // when ii = 0
    // lookupFld[0] is 10 
    // so MasterField[10] /* fld10 */ is represented by split[0] /* alpha */
}
```

Comment: The data is tab delimited not fixed width. This is what I am doing now. I split the first line which is the header. Then as I parse each line I validate the split header in a switch statement to see which field I have been provided. Then I write the data for the field into the corresponding class getter/setter.